# How do I handle keyboard input on a modal dialog box?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a modal dialog box, and I would like to close it when either the "Cancel" button is clicked or the escape key is pressed. How do I handle an escape key press in the dialog box procedure?

Here is my current dialog box procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return true;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDC_CANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, false);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }

    // this doesn't work
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
            EndDialog(hDlg, false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, false);
        return true;

    default:
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know that if I changed my modal dialog box to a modeless dialog box, I could use an accelerator table to make Escape an accelerator for the cancel button, but I want to keep my dialog box modal. Using `SetFocus(hDlg)` under `case WM_INITDIALOG:` doesn't capture keyboard input, and I'm out of ideas.

How can I handle keyboard input in a modal dialog box?

Comment: You shouldn't need to anything; if the `[OK]` button has the id `IDOK` and and `[Cancel]` button has the id `IDCANCEL` then it's all handled for you by the default dialog processing.  The above ids are pre-defined see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/win32-predefined-symbols?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both Richard Critten and GPT-4 for providing this answer: I can simply handle the command IDCANCEL, which is automatically sent when Esc is pressed on a dialog box. To make things cleaner, I can change my Cancel button to send the same command, IDCANCEL. That gives us this dialog box procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return true;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDCANCEL:  // note this change
            EndDialog(hDlg, false);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }

    // no need to handle key presses

    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, false);
        return true;

    default:
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to handle `WM_CLOSE` at all now, actually.  If you return `false`, Windows will translate it into an appropriate `WM_COMMAND` message for you, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations